# 갈매기살 (lit. seagull meat) pork cut name origin

Tags: etymology, food

In Korean there is a cut of pork called 갈매기살, which literally translates into "seagull meat." The first time I heard this, I was shocked and thought they had actual seagull meat on the menu. I was told it is just a name for the cut of pork, but no one knew the origin of the name. Why is this cut called 갈매기살?

[image: pork cuts in Korean]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not seagull :)

It seems to be flow like this.

'횡격막(diaphragm) -> spoken korean 가로막(horizontal block)' + '-이(er)' + '살(flesh)' = '가로막이살' -> '가ㄹㅗ매기살' - 'ㅗ' = '갈매기살'

[Source](http://m.tip.daum.net/question/39516157)

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense now! Can I suggest adding a citation? Perhaps it was https://namu.wiki/w/갈매기살 ?

Comment: No. It was Daum tips. http://tip.daum.net/question/39516157

Comment: Ah, just submitted an edit: https://korean.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/578